# permanently add binary to path on mac os

Tags: macos, shell, path, binary, executable

I am trying to permanently add a binary to the path variable on mac os. I have read several posts and blogs, it just does not work.

The question: given a directory /dir which contains an executable foo, how can I make it such that I can execute foo in the commandline without having to type export PATH... etc., and without having to move the foo executable to the bin folder?

I know there exists several scripts that are run on startup and whenever you open a command prompt, I just cannot seem to find the correct one. If I manually execute the export PATH... command and then do foo, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the export command works for you, just add it to either ~/.zshrc (on zsh) or ~/.bashrc (on bash).